# My java program is not outputting everything it is supposed to. No errors

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

My code takes an input (first color choice then the amount); asks if i would like to do it again (if yes then it repeats the process of entering the color and amount); then it passes the values to tow different methods that calculate the price of each color which then return the calculated amount back to main.

The problem is when is put in a second color (after is asks "would you like to make another purchase?"), it outputs only the calculated price of the second input and not the first.

here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String answer, color;
    int red_gallons=0;
    int red_gallons_2=0;
    int green_gallons_2=0;
    int green_gallons=0;
    double green_cost=0;
    double red_cost=0;
    System.out.println("which paint color do you wish to purchase (g or r)");  
    color = in.next();

    switch (color)
    {
        case"G":
        case "g":
        {
            System.out.println("how many full gallons of paint do you need");           
            green_gallons = in.nextInt();
            break;
        }
        case"R":
        case "r":
        {
            System.out.println("how many full gallons of paint do you need");           
            red_gallons = in.nextInt();
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Would you like to make another purchase? (y/n)");
    answer = in.next();

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
    {
        System.out.println("which paint color do you wish to purchase (g or r)");   
        color = in.next();
        switch (color)
        {
            case"G":
            case "g":
            {
                System.out.println("how many full gallons of paint do you need");           
                green_gallons_2 = in.nextInt();
                break;
            }
            case"R":
            case "r":
            {
                System.out.println("how many full gallons of paint do you need");           
                red_gallons_2 = in.nextInt();
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("");
    }
    if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("g"))
    {
        green_cost = green_paint(green_gallons,green_gallons_2);
    }
    else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("r"))
    {
        red_cost = red_paint(red_gallons,red_gallons_2);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("");
    }

    double total_cost = total_bill(red_cost, green_cost);
    String store = store_title();
    thank_you(store, red_cost, green_cost, total_cost ); //BILL

}

//calculates cost of red paint an returns it to main
public static double red_paint(int r_amount_1, int r_amount_2 )
{
    double cost_of_red = 21.95;
    double total_red = cost_of_red*(r_amount_1+r_amount_2);             
    return total_red;                                   
}

//calculates cost of green paint and returns it to main
public static double green_paint(int g_amount_1, int g_amount_2)
{
    double cost_of_green = 19.95;
    double total_green = cost_of_green*(g_amount_1+g_amount_2); 
    return total_green;                         
}

//title of store, returned to main
public static String store_title()
{
    String str = "\n\n*******************\n*THE RAINBOW STORE*\n*******************";
    return str;
}

//calculates bill with tax, and returns it to main  
public static double total_bill(double red$, double green$) 
{
    double bill = red$+green$;              
    double plus_tax = bill+(bill*.08);      
    return plus_tax;                        
}

//prints the bill
public static void thank_you(String stor, double red, double green, double total) 
{
    System.out.println(stor);
    System.out.printf("Red Paint: $%.2f",red);      System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Green Paint: $%.2f",green);  System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Total: $%.2f",total);        System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Thank You for shopping at the Rainbow Store!");

}
```

Comment: Please learn to use switch case properly. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no evidence of any basic debugging having been applied.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("g"))
{
    green_cost = green_paint(green_gallons,green_gallons_2);
}
else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("r"))
{
    red_cost = red_paint(red_gallons,red_gallons_2);
}
else
{
    System.out.print("");
}
```

The `if`s here are the problem. The calculations should not be conditional.